# How to add a server image control to html container using innerHTML =

Tags: asp.net

I have a td that I want to inject with a server image control (asp.net) using innerHTML = "". The webcontrol's toString is giving the type.

Is there a way to extract the generated  from the server control?
Or, is there a different solution...?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb);
img.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(writer));
td.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();
```

or the more obvious

```
td.Controls.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question looks like you're asking how to inject an image at runtime into a table cell.

If the table cell is part of your ASP.NET page, you could do something like:

```
<td id="imageCell" runat="server"/>
```

In your code behind:

```
Image img = new Image();
img.ImageUrl = "mypic.jpg";
imageCell.Controls.Add(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RenderControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.rendercontrol.aspx) method to get the output HTML.

Ex:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var img = new Image();

        var hw = new HtmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
        img.RenderControl(hw);

        hw.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<img src="" style="border-width:0px;" />
```